# Where can we find the host name in device information?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

When I sign in the Admin console of Google Workspace, I can find the device information and host name at Devices > Mobile and endpoints > Devices.
I noticed several devices which installed the endpoint verification can have the information of `Host name` such as below;

- hoge'sMacBook.local
- X2Fuga

etc.

So I wondered if I can get this information from the APIs, but I couldn't find them at the moment.

Does anyone have any information about this?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this, and I initially thought that you can use [Devices API](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/devices/list) under Google Cloud Identity to check for Device Information that is installed with Endpoint Verification. But after doing further research regarding its [REST Resources](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/devices#Device) provided below:

> JSON representation

```json
{
  "name": string,
  "createTime": string,
  "lastSyncTime": string,
  "ownerType": enum (DeviceOwnership),
  "model": string,
  "osVersion": string,
  "deviceType": enum (DeviceType),
  "serialNumber": string,
  "assetTag": string,
  "imei": string,
  "meid": string,
  "wifiMacAddresses": [
    string
  ],
  "networkOperator": string,
  "manufacturer": string,
  "releaseVersion": string,
  "brand": string,
  "buildNumber": string,
  "kernelVersion": string,
  "basebandVersion": string,
  "enabledDeveloperOptions": boolean,
  "otherAccounts": [
    string
  ],
  "enabledUsbDebugging": boolean,
  "securityPatchTime": string,
  "bootloaderVersion": string,
  "encryptionState": enum (EncryptionState),
  "androidSpecificAttributes": {
    object (AndroidAttributes)
  },
  "managementState": enum (ManagementState),
  "compromisedState": enum (CompromisedState),
  "endpointVerificationSpecificAttributes": {
    object (EndpointVerificationSpecificAttributes)
  }
}
```

It seems that the host name information is currently  not available. So I would suggest you could submit it as a [feature request here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new)

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I will submit the FR soon.